# Can not access directory from command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

As the title said: I can't access a directory from commandline. I am tring to access the `D:\` drive like this:

```
cd D:\\
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have edited the question and put a screen shot ,I hope You get what I mean

Comment: That site (or another site hosted at the same IP) is blacklisted in my security software.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is this:

```
cd /d D:\
```

Comment: This works ,Thanks 
Really The syntax I always use is cd D:\\ , but I do not know why It did not work this time , any way I ve tried your answer and it worked

Comment: This works ,Thanks 
Really The syntax I always use is cd D:\\ , but I do not know why It did not work this time , any way I ve tried your answer and it worked